# Устройство с состоянием вида x(n+1)=a*x(n)+b(mod127)

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Здравствуйте. Задали написать программу,.. условие-то есть, но какое-то для меня оно плохопонимаемое. Вот оно:

> Пусть некоторое устройство содержит в качестве состояния число от 0 до 126. В каждый следующий момент времени число меняется по формуле  x(n+1)=a*x(n)+b(mod127), где а=10, b=11.  Создать класс, отображающий это устройство.
>
> В классе должны быть функции-члены:
>
> 1. конструктор, имеющий аргумент – начальное состояние,
> 2. функция, переводящая устройство в следующее состояние,
> 3. функция, выводящая на экран состояние устройства.

x(n+1) и х(n) - следующее и предыдущее значения? Что это вообще? Можете намекнуть алгоритм?  Нет бы лектору задать простое задание на проверку усвоения информации...

Answer (score 3):

кто мешает создать класс, в котором будет одно поле целого типа, где будет хранится текущее состояние, конструктор с одним параметром, который будет выставлять это состояние и один метод, типа такого

```
class Generator {
private:
    int curr; // поле текущего значения
public:
    int getNext() {
        int x = (10*curr + 11) % 127; // тут я не ручаюсь, что точно расшифровал формулу
        // но по идее, именно так должно быть
        curr = x;
        return x;
    }
    int getCurrent() { return curr; }
Generator(int start) {
    curr = start % 127; // поделим сразу, что бы точно было в заданном диапазоне.
}
}
```

дальше думаю сможете сами:)

Answer (score 0):

Видимо, да, подразумевается, что `x(n)` — текущее состояние, а `x(n + 1)` — следующее.

Храните состояние в объекте; на метод «функция, переводящая устройство в следующее состояние» делаете положенное `this.state = (this.a * this.state + this.b) % 127;` (если я правильно понял формулу).

(Хранить `a` и `b` в классе или объявить их константами — сугубо Ваше дело.)

Comment: Боюсь Вы не до конца меня поняли... В каждый следующий момент времени число меняется по формуле x(n+1)=a*x(n)+b(mod127)-Эта строчка в основном не понятна(

Вот есть число, оно изменится по формуле этой, потом ставлю полученное число в формулу и получаю другое? И сколько так делать?

Comment: Делать так каждый раз, когда вызовете определенную ф-цию класса, которая описана в задании как "переводящая устройство в следующее состояние"